# Is there a "SHELL IN PRIVATE" mode for bash?

Tags: bash, security

When I use a browser, I can "browse in private" if I don't want my browser history recorded on the local machine.  But what if I'm typing commands in the bash shell and maybe passwords, and I don't want that stored in my command history, but at the same time I don't want to wipe out my command history?  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: No matter your settings, **don't** type passwords that matter as arguments on the command line!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: My answer was marked ACCEPTED before the question was marked as duplicate. The reference points out a solution possibly superior to the three I list below, depending on your use-case, so I'll repeat it here: Temporarily turn off history logging by typing `set +o history`, and restore history logging by typing `set -o history`.

ORIGINAL ANSWER(S):
In `bash`, there are a few ways to manually create the environment you seem to want, all involving some combination of the internal `bash`variables, `HISTCONTROL`, `HISTFILE` and `HISTIGNORE`.

In the paragraphs below, quotations are verbatim from `man bash`.

1] You could start a shell with `HISTFILE` unset, in which case "the command history is not saved when a shell exits".

2] You could manually set `HISTCONTROL` to include the string `ignorespace`, in which case "lines which begin with a space  character  are  not saved  in  the history list.

3] You could manually set `HISTIGNORE` to `*`, or to something more specific, in which case lines matching your glob pattern(s) will not be saved. For this option, do read the `man` page carefully, because there are several caveats and gotchas. That section of the `man` page is short and clear, and its good practice to read it anyway, so I'm not cutting and pasting it here.